# How do i get id from table rows and pass to other page

Tags: php, html, session, anchor

I am trying to develop an application form app. [image].

I want to be able to click on an application id and be able to generate the application form in details. So am using Sessions and it only works for the last id in the database. 
Basically passing an application ID into a session then calling it as a parameter for the next page. If this method cant work, could there be another? Hope am clear enough. 
Here is my code.

```
<td>

    <a href="applicants_details.php"> <?php echo $Applicant->getApplicationID(); ?>
   <?php php $_SESSION["SELECTEDID"] = $Applicant->GetApplicationID(); ?>
</td>
```

Comment: how about doing `<a href="applicants_details.php?id=<?=$Applicant->GetApplicationID()?>">` then you can do `$_GET['id']` in `applicants_details.php`

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. Can I personally message you to help me with other issues that am having?

Comment: Mwewa no problem.  :)

Comment: +260975662119 for my WhatsApp. Will be glad to hear from you.

Comment: let's do it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36832/willie-mwewa)

Answer (score 1):

Use $_GET,

> applications.php

```
<a href="applicants_details.php?applicant_id=<?php echo $Applicant->GetApplicationID(); ?>"><?php echo $Applicant->GetApplicationID(); ?><\a>
```

> applicant_details.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET['applicant_id'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code on the table to:

```
<td>

<a href="applicants_details.php?id=<?php echo $Applicant->getApplicationID(); ?>"> 
<?php echo $Applicant->getApplicationID(); ?>
</a>
</td>
```

Then on the next page you can get the ID with:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>
```